# How to pass encoded parameters to call contract getter fuctions

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, nodejs

I have an array (i.e. `functionNames[]`)  of getter functions's names of my contract and another array (i.e. `finalGettersParams`) of encoded parameters (which has been populated from `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters`) of that getter functions.

```
  finalGettersParams = [ Result { __length__: 0 },
  Result {
    '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    __length__: 1 },
  Result {
    '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    __length__: 2 } 
    ]
```

now i want to call all getter functions with above available information. Is it possible? One possible solution which i am trying (but its not working, being incomplete) ....

```
for(j=0; j<functionNames.length; j++) {
      myFunc = functionNames[j].funcName;
      try {
        res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](...finalGettersParams[?????????]).call({from: account1}) // here i need help 
        console.log("Getter output", res);
      } catch (error) {
         console.log("Getter ERROR", error);
      }
```

Anyone can suggest me how to proceed, further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should generally work for you:

```
...Object.values(finalGettersParams[j]).slice(0, -1)
```

However, it implicitly assumes that the values will always appear in increasing order of their keys, and that the value of the `__length__` key will always appear last.

So in order to "remove all doubts", you can also use this:

```
...[...Array(finalGettersParams[j].__length__).keys()].map(key => finalGettersParams[j][key])
```

Comment: yes, it works for me ... thanks a lot... you always help me and avoid my head from burning....

Comment: @AmirAli: Hahaha, no problem; see updated answer just in case it matters (though I'm not saying you should use it, if the original suggestion works well enough).

Comment: yes, _length_ always apear last (as per output generated from web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters) ... anyhow, it will also helpful for generic solution ... thanks again...